# How to put radio button inside the output table?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, arrays

How to put radio button inside the status, 2 radio buttons (approved and disapproved) and the checked radio button will be save in database as well under status field.
[image]

**This is my codes.. patient[6] is the status**

```
$sql = "select patientid, firstname, lastname, gender, patienttype, philhealth, status from patients where lastname LIKE '%" . $_POST["key"] . "%' or philhealth LIKE '%" . $_POST["key"] . "%' ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        $rownum = 0;
        $bgcolor = "";


        while($patient = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $rownum += 1;
            if($rownum == 2)
            {
                $bgcolor = "#FFF";
                $rownum = 0;
            }
            else
            { $bgcolor = "#f9f9f9"; }
            $approved_checked = $patient[6] == 'Approved' ? 'checked' : '';
            echo "
            <tr id='" . $patient[0] . "' style='background: " . $bgcolor . "' onclick='openphilhealthapproval() '>
                    <td id='td27_cell1' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[5] . " </td>
                    <td id='td27_cell2' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[0] . "</td>
                    <td id='td27_cell3' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[1] . " " . $patient[2] . "</td>
                    <td id='td27_cell4' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[3] . "</td> 
                    <td id='td27_cell5' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[4] . "</td>
                    <td id='td27_cell6' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[6] . "</td>

                </tr>
            ";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the content of this `TD` element into your status `TD` element. Also you need to replace `***patientID***` signs with the patientID when you build your HTML. You could see the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ckexaeq6/).

```
<td>
      <input type="radio" name="statusradio***patientID***" value="approved" id="approvedradio***patientID***"/>
      <label for="approvedradio***patientID***">approved</label>
      <input type="radio" name="statusradio***patientID***" value="disapproved" id="disapprovedradio***patientID***"/>
      <label for="disapprovedradio***patientID***">disapproved</label>
</td>
```